# How can I reset the Storage Manager password on a IBM DS5020 Storage Array on network using telnet?

Tags: storage, ibm, datastore

I have an IBM DS5020 Storage Array to which the Storage Manager password is lost, but it has been configured on a network and the IP Address is known.

How can I reset the password remotely without using the serial port?

When I open an rlogin session using PuTTY, the connection is refused.
If I connect via the Telnet connection, I am prompted for a VxWorks login.

The Firmware version is 07.70.23.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These steps worked for me on firmware version 7.70:

First, connect remotely on telnet using the user name: **shellUsr**

The password for **shellUsr** is **wy3oo&w4**

Alternate passwords may be **infiniti** or **y2llojp** according to [IBM System Storage:User and password for serial port on DS4700 (fw version 7.15)](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014147954#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014215217)

Next, enter the command **spriMenuPwdReset** and enter **y** at the confirmation.

Alternate commands for older firmware versions (6.60 and 7.60) are **clearSYMbolPassword** and **symbolPwdReset**

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I wanted to add a couple of things that I didn't know until I did an nmap of the storage subsystem. On older DS4700 systems, pretty 513 (rlogin) is what you'll need to use to shell in remotely (if you have the ip of the system.)